# Spotify token returning error 415 angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, spotify

I want to get an access token from the Spotify api
Here is my request :

```js
this.http.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
      headers: { 
        'Authorization' : "Basic " + CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("ID:Secret")),
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      params: {
        grant_type : "authorization_code",
        code : code,
        redirect_uri : "REDIRECT URL"
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

I get this error in the console:

> "Http failure response for https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token: 415 OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create a `HttpParams` object with the params before, like:

```js
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
    .append("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    .append("code", "code")
    .append("redirect_uri", "redirect_uri");

this.http.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", httpParams.toString(), {
      headers: { 
        'Authorization' : "Basic " + CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("ID:Secret")),
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: Not Working :(-

Comment: Try send the params as a body `this.http.post("url", httpParams.toString(), {headers: {...}})` @XetaWays

Comment: did you get any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if anyone is looking for a solution:

This is what finally worked for me:

```
 getToken(){
   const client_id = env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID; 
   const client_secret = env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET; 
   const url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
   const encoded = btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret);

   const headers = new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Authorization': `Basic ${encoded}`
   });

   const httpParams = new HttpParams()
   .set('grant_type', 'client_credentials')

   return this.http.post(url, httpParams , {headers : headers}).pipe(
     map(res => {
       let data = res
       return data;
     })
   )  
  }
```